# VB compile error when trying to use String.Compare

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I am trying to check if the password is the same or not (in terms of caps too) using vb.net. But the line

```
 result = String.Compare(actPassword,userPassword)
```

keep giving error "Compile Error: Expected:("

```
Private Sub Login_Click()
    'Check to see if data is entered into the UserName combo box
     If IsNull(Me.cmbLoginID) Or Me.cmbLoginID = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a User Name.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.cmbLoginID.SetFocus
       Exit Sub
      End If
      'Check to see if data is entered into the password box
       If IsNull(Me.txtPW) Or Me.txtPW = "" Then
           MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
            Me.txtPW.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        End If
      'Check value of password in tblEmployees to see if this matches value chosen in combo box
      Dim userPassword As String
      Dim actPassword As String
      Dim result As Integer
      userPassword = txtPW.Text
      actPassword = DLookup("EmpPassword", "Employee", "EmployeeID='" + Me.cmbLoginID.Value + "'")
      result = String.Compare(actPassword,userPassword)
      If result = -1 Then
        'Close logon form and open splash screen
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login", acSaveNo
            DoCmd.OpenForm "HomePage"
         Else
        MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
         Me.txtPW.SetFocus
        End If
     'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown
        intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
        If intLogonAttempts > 3 Then
          MsgBox "You do not have access to this database. Please contact your system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
       End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no `String.Compare()` in VBA (There is in VB.NET)

Also, please note VB.NET is not VBA

Use [StrComp](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Use StrComp**

```
result = StrComp(actPassword, userPassword, vbTextCompare)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While `String.Compare()` exists in VB.Net, I don't think it does in VBA. In any case, what you're doing is wrong anyway.

`String.Compare` can return *any* integer and it will only return zero if they match. Your particular test (comparing against `-1`) is only checking one possibility, that the actual password is *less* than the desired one, and it's only checking for *one* of the possible negative values.

You would be better off in that case with something like:

```
if result <> 0 Then
```

---

However, if you just want to *compare* two strings for equality in VBA (rather than figure out the relative ordering), you can just use:

```
if actPassword = userPassword Then
```